# Nested stored procedure and transaction scope

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, scope

I have a main working procedure and an accompanying logging procedure. I'm looking for verification on what my assumptions are with sql server 2008. The desired result is that SP1 does whatever work it can do and calls SP2 along the way to log progress. SP2 work is committed regardless of whether or not SP1 encounters an error that would cause it's transaction to rollback.

Does what I have look safe? Do I need to name transaction in SP2 differently?

```
------------------------------------------------------- SP1 pseudocode
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- Do stuff
    -- log progress
    exec SP2( getutcdate(), 'source_is_sp1','message for progress');

    -- Do more stuff
    -- log progress
    exec SP2( getutcdate(), 'source_is_sp1','message for progress');

    -- etc

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    RETURN 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- error handling not important
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    return @StepNumber -- not important 
END CATCH


------------------------------------------------------- SP2

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP2]

    @Source as nvarchar(100),
    @Timestamp as datetime,
    @Message as nvarchar(4000)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @Timestamp is null
    BEGIN
        set @Timestamp = GETUTCDATE();
    END

    IF @Source IS NOT NULL AND @Message IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            INSERT INTO LOG(LOGTIMESTAMP, SOURCEVCH, MESSAGEVCH) 
                    VALUES (@Timestamp, @Source, @Message);
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END
END
```

Comment: In this example both writes to your log will be rolled back when the outer transaction's ROLLBACK is called and conversely committed when the outer transaction's COMMIT is called. If you are using transactions in SP's you should examine the @@TRANCOUNT to make sure it is safe to commit. Perhaps logging as you are doing but adding a log entry after ROLLBACK to note the error that caused the rollback.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah I would want to do a log message in the catch block as well. I really would like to record the full progress as it happens, even if I had to rollback the transaction. So my assumptions were wrong. After getting a more in depth crash course it seems all of those inner transactions would be rolled back. From what I've recently learned, local variable tables that insert/updates/deletes would not be rolled back. SO I could define a local @Logs, manipulate that along the way, and finally log it at the end into the master LOG table at the end of the try or in the catch.